# norwegian characters in filename in assets folder giving me error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, assets

Android; Norwegian characters in the filename (assets folder) give me an error in eclipse.
Example:

- shrek.jpg - works
- øve.jpg   - doesn't work
- åpne.jpg  - doesn't work

I can't compile the android app because of these (Å, Ø, Æ) characters. When I delete them everything works.
Can somebody help me with this? I need to use them.

[See picture](http://prntscr.com/4qlvgd)

Answer (score 0):

...just rename the files to not use Norwegian characters? I can't think of any reason why your filenames need to include those characters.

Comment: Because, If I want toons characters in norwegian name than it is not same in english.

Comment: I think that is something with eclipse and foreign language I just found something about it on this site:  http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/10/31/foreign-characters-for-the-eclipse-build-system/

Comment: You're not displaying the filenames to your user. Your filenames don't have to match your character names, you could have the character be named åpne but the filename be bob.jpg, you just need to map from one to the other.

Comment: I bought Picture Quiz source, quiz is generated from pictures filename into quiz english alphabet only, there is when I get problem. Eclipse will not permit special, foreign letter i  filename.

Comment: Eclipse do not show any error at beginning, only when I try to build apk.